# Switch between CSS variables based on states

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, electron

I'm trying to implement color-themes into my react app and went with css-variables and the basics work out so far.

However I'm also trying to apply the theme to an SVG icon that changes the color based on a state. It goes from grey to a color which is defined by the theme when a phone gets connected to a device.

I have a themes.css which looks like this:

```
    :root {
    --fillInactive: #7c7c7c;
}

[data-theme='Blue'] {
    --fillHover: #708fa8;
    --fillActive: #3f77a4;
}

[data-theme='Red'] {
    --fillHover: #cd6969;
    --fillActive: #cd2424;

}

[data-theme='Green'] {
    --fillHover: #85b08e;
    --fillActive: #41ad56;
}

[data-theme='White'] {
    --fillHover: #9f9f9f;
    --fillActive: #ffffff;
}
```

My topbar.js looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./topbar.scss";
import "../components/themes.scss"

const electron = window.require('electron');
const { ipcRenderer } = electron;

const TopBar = () => {

  const Store = window.require('electron-store');
  const store = new Store();

  const [phoneState, setPhoneState] = useState("#7c7c7c");
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(store.get("colorTheme"));

  const plugged = () => {
    setPhoneState("#3f77a4");
  }

  const unplugged = () => {
    setPhoneState("#7c7c7c");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.send('statusReq');
    ipcRenderer.on("plugged", plugged);
    ipcRenderer.on("unplugged", unplugged);

    return function cleanup() {
      ipcRenderer.removeListener('plugged',   plugged);
      ipcRenderer.removeListener('unplugged', unplugged);
      
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="topbar" data-theme={theme}}>
      <div className="topbar__info">
        <svg className="topbar__icon">
          <use xlinkHref="./svg/phone.svg#phone" color={phoneState}></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>

  );
};

export default TopBar;
```

My TopBar.scss looks like this:

```
.topbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

    height: 66px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000000;

    &__info {
      margin-left: 3rem;
    }

    &__icon {
      &__phone {
      }
      margin-top: 1rem;
      margin-right:1rem;
      width:  1rem;
      height: 1rem;
    }
  }
```

For now I hardcoded a blue color into my JS, but would like that the property "--fillActive" is set for the SVG when the phone is plugged, based on the chosen Theme.
When the phone is unplugged it should switch to "--fillInactive" so it greys out again.

I hope my question is specific enough. I tried googling for a solution, but I'm not even sure that what I'm trying to do is the right way, hence trying to find a good search query is rather difficult. I saw some solutions where you can just override a variable through javascript, but I would like that the properties stay as they are and that I just choose between the two to set the correct color based on the state.

Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an idea, the phoneState could contain the actual phone state: plugged/unplugged:

```js
const [phoneState, setPhoneState] = useState(() => 'unplugged');
```

Then the corresponding callback would toggle the state:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.send('statusReq');
    ipcRenderer.on("plugged", setPhoneState(() => 'plugged'));
    ipcRenderer.on("unplugged", setPhoneState(() => 'unplugged'));

    return function cleanup() { ... },
 []);
```

In this case the phoneState can be used for a dynamic class of some element, for example:

```js
return (
    <div className="topbar" data-theme={theme}}>
      <div className={`topbar__info topbar__info--${phoneState}`}>
        <svg className="topbar__icon">
          <use xlinkHref="./svg/phone.svg#phone" ></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Then when the css vars are applied, they would have corresponding values according to the active theme.

```scss
.topbar {
  &__info{
    &--plugged{
      color: var(--fillActive);
    }
    &--unplugged{
      color: var(--fillInactive);
    }
  }
}
```